# add_post_meta displays in admin edit area

Tags: wp-admin, post-meta, wp-insert-post

I use a simple way to add_post_meta() to wp_insert_post(). Everything's working fine, except my meta box doesn't appear in admin area. Is there a simple way to do that?

```
<?php 
$condition = $_POST['condition']; // I am taking the field from my form and pass it to a variable
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); // $new_post is an array with my arguments
add_post_meta($pid, 'condition', $condition, true);
// Then i can display my meta box within post with echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'condition', true );
```

Comment: No one, no idea? :/

Answer (score 0):

Just add custom-field support to your custom post;

```
register_post_type( 'YourPosts',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'YourPosts' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'YourPost' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'custom-fields',
        )
        )
    );
```